# How to get the value of Radiobutton Listitem using Javascript

Tags: c#-4.0, radiobuttonlist

I want to get the value of the selected item of a radiobutton List using javascript.
My code is:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="Radio" RepeatColumns="3" CssClass="textfont">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">First</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Second</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Third</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And this is my Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendParameters() { 
        var Id = '<%=HiddenField1.Value%>';
        var ddl1 = document.getElementById("Radio").checked; 
</script>
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please view the source of the resulting web page and post the resulting radio button html.  This will make it easier to answer because then the question comes down to plain HTML and jQuery.

The Reason is asp often changes the name of the ID, unless you add ClientIDMode="Static" to your control.

Once that is done this should do it:

---

```
var chosenValue = $('input:radio[id="Radio"]:checked').val();

alert(chosenValue);
```

Comment: You were right. Although I had completed this earlier but I did in the same way. I inspected the webpage and then used the same reference.

Comment: @iti-tyagi make sure you use the ClientIDMode="Static" if possible. If you use the ASP generated name it could change in the future when you move things around or future versions.